# How to mock Azure Storage Account in C# using Moq?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, rest

I have a service `IBlobService` :

```
public interface IBlobService
{
    public Task<BlobInfo> GetBlobAsync(string name);
    public Task<IEnumerable<string>> ListBlobsAsync();
    public Task UploadFileBlobAsync(string filePath, string fileName);
    public Task UploadContentBlobAsync(string content, string fileName);
    public Task DeleteBlobAsync(string blobName);
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `GetBlobAsync` method within my `BlobService` class:

```
public async Task<BlobInfo> GetBlobAsync(string name)
{
    var client = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(name);
    var blobDownloadInfo = await client.DownloadContentAsync();
    return new BlobInfo(blobDownloadInfo.Value.Content, blobDownloadInfo.Value.Details.ContentType);
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use Moq to implement my test. I am relatively new to Moq. Any ideas or guidance?

I have tried to review this blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/

but i'm still finding myself stuck.  I am trying to figure out the best way to implement my test.

Comment: Well, If this is about what I think this is about, then you need to inject your `BlobService` under test with a mocked `BlobContainerClient` that is set up to return a Mock of a `BlobClient` in its `GetBlobClient( string )` method. That BlobClient-Mock in turn needs to be set up for whatever you then want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a unit test for testing the blobservice or a class *using* the `IblobService` ?

If it's a class using your `IBlobService` then you need to mock the `IBlobService`

like this

```cs
...
public void Test1() {
   var blobServiceMocked = new Mock<IBlobService>();
   blobServiceMocked.Setup(e => e.GetBlobAsync(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(new BlobInfo(){ ... }); 
blobServiceMocked.Object;
... 

// assert
  _methodThatTakesIBlobservice(blobServiceMocked.Object);
...
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This actually is exactly what I was looking for. Since I had a IBlobService , I ended up mocking that in my test.

Comment: That's the way to do it @NabeelAfsar

Comment: Hi @NabeelAfsar Could you accept my answer? Makes it easier for other to find it and I would appreciate it a lot